# Django Signals File

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

How does Django know where exactly to look for Signal functions? Like which .py file to search for receiver functions? Does it search for every single file and execute the function if found?

Tried reading docs but didn't help much.

Comment: It doesn't, you need to load the file.

Answer (score 2):

Django uses signal registration to determine where to locate signal receiver functions. Imagine you want to create a social media app where every user has a profile page. Technically, you can't allow users to create a profile page manually; instead, it should be created automatically when the user is created. Let's assume you have a model like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField()
```

To utilize signals for automatically creating a profile page for each user, you need to create a `signals.py` file within your Django app and then import it in the `app.py` file. This allows you to define signal handlers and connect them to the `post_save` signal of the user model, making sure that a profile page is created automatically whenever a new user is created.

**Signals.py**

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from .models import Profile
  
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL 
  
 @receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
 def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): 
     if created: 
         Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

As I said, you need to import `signals.py` file into `app.py` file to allows you to connect to the `post_save` signal of the user model, making sure that a profile page is created automatically whenever a new user is created.

**app.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'your_app_name'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

[`Reference`](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-and-use-signals-in-django/amp/)

Answer (score 1):

The other option that works is creating your signals function in a `signals.py` file for example:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

And after creating your signal function, you can use it in your `models.py` as follows

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .signals import create_profile

# your model definition

# the use of the signal
pre_save.connect(create_profile, Profile)
```

To connect a receiver, you use `Signal.connect()` method as shown above.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

> How does django know where exactly to look for Signal functions? like which `.py` file to search for receiver functions?

It **doesn't**. You just register signals through the [**`@receiver`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver) or directly connecting it with [**`.connect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal.connect). This thus means that you can connect handlers anywhere in the codebase to a signal.

The only problem is that not all files in the code base are per se interpreted (directly or after a certain amount of time). So you will need to ensure that Django loads the file.

This means that you should either load these in a file Django will automatically look for, like `models.py`, or you enforce loading with the [**`.ready(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) of the app config (that is loaded for that app).

You thus can load the module with:

```
# app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # …

    def ready(self):
        import app_name.signals  # noqa
```

where `signals` can be any module, although `signals` is of course a common name to use.